# NSDictionary writeToFile fails while objects are valid, permission is 0k

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, nsdictionary

Why `NSDictionary` cannot be written?? I have checked the content of the dictionary: all the instances are of `NSString` and `NSNumber`. I checked permissions: a text file with the same name at the same path is written well. Of course, my dictionary is not empty.

```
NSString *file = ...
NSDictionary *dict = ...

// check dictionary keys
BOOL wrong = NO;
for (id num in [dict allKeys]) {
    if (![num isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        wrong = YES;
        break;
    }
}
if (wrong) {
    NSLog(@"First");
}
// check dictionary values
wrong = NO;
for (id num in [dict allValues]) {
    if (![num isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        wrong = YES;
        break;
    }
}
if (wrong) {
    NSLog(@"Second");
}

if (![dict writeToFile:file atomically:YES]) {
    // 0k, let's try to create a text file
    NSLog(@"Names writing error!");
    [@"Something here... .. ." writeToFile:file atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

Output: "Names writing error!"
Text file is created successfully.

Comment: Where do you write it? In Bundle? If that's the case you can't, at least on iOS, you have to write at a new file path.

Comment: @Larme in a folder on the desktop, Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vadian points out, you cannot write plist with numeric keys. But you can use `NSKeyedArchiver`:

```
NSURL *documents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:false error:nil];
NSURL *fileURL = [documents URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

// this will not work

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@1: @"foo", @2: @"bar"};
BOOL success = [dictionary writeToFile:fileURL.path atomically:true];
NSLog(@"plist %@", success ? @"success" : @"failure");

// this will

fileURL = [documents URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.bplist"];
success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dictionary toFile:fileURL.path];
NSLog(@"archive %@", success ? @"success" : @"failure");
```

And you can read it back with `NSKeyedUnarchiver`:

```
// to read it back

NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fileURL.path];
NSLog(@"dictionary2 = %@", dictionary2);
```

Note, you can do this with any class that conforms (and properly implements) `NSCoding`. Fortunately, `NSDictionary` conforms already. You have to make sure that any objects inside the dictionary, also conform (both `NSString` and `NSNumber` do). If you had a custom object in your dictionary, you'd have to make it properly conform yourself.

This is all described in the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

Answer (score 6):

Writing out a dictionary creates a property list, and according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html) all keys in a property list must be **strings**.

> ... and although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to
>   be objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the
>   collections are not property-list objects.

`NSNumber` objects as keys are not supported.